# Building Docker Image with Gradle fails with "COPY failed: no source files were specified"

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, dockerfile, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am new to Gradle. I am trying to build a Dockerfile from within my **build.gradle**

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:tomcat-7.7.0

COPY build/libs/*.war /camunda/webapps/
COPY camunda/ /camunda/webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/
COPY definitions/ /camunda/definitions/
```

#### build.gradle

```
    task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
        push = false
        dockerfile = file("Dockerfile")
        version release.version
        tag = "${docker_registry_url}/camunda"
        doFirst {
            copy {
                from war
                into stageDir
            }
            copy {
                from "${projectDir}/camunda/"
                into stageDir
            }
            copy {
                from "${projectDir}/definitions/"
                into stageDir
            }
        }
    }
```

### Output

#### ./gradlew clean build buildDocker --info

> Execution failed for task ':buildDocker'.
>   Docker execution failed
>     Command line [docker build -t 73299472920.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/camunda:0.0.0.uncommitted-71119c2 /Users/amx/Code/backend/jclaim/build/docker] returned:
>
> COPY failed: no source files were specified

I am able to build this image manually from the same **Dockerfile** using **docker build -t** but somehow it fails in Gradle buildDocker task.

It even works when I do not add the last two **COPY**

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:tomcat-7.7.0

COPY build/libs/*.war /camunda/webapps/
```

But I have to COPY the other two artifacts as well.

**My Docker plugin for Docker:**

> se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2

**Gradle Version:**

> Gradle 5.1.1

Please help me fix this.

Comment: It's probably a better idea to go with a different plugin than the Transmode plugin. Their last release was in 2014 and the implementation isn't super flexible. It may serve your needs but you are probably better off with this plugin: https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I got to work.

I had to add :

```
doFirst {
    copy {
        from war
        into stageDir
    }
       copy {
           from "${projectDir}/camunda/"
           into stageDir
       }
       copy {
           from "${projectDir}/definitions/"
           into stageDir
       }
}
```

in my **build.gradle**. This would copy all my artifacts into `build/docker/` and then my `Dockerfile` just need the filenames in their `COPY src dest` and NOT  `COPY /path/to/src/ dest`.

This fixed it.

Thank u everyone!